# The argument type 'Future' cant be assigned to the parameter type 'List<LatLng>'

Tags: json, google-maps, flutter, dart, polyline

I am using Google Maps within my Flutter project. I am trying to parse a json file in my assets so that I can use its Latitude and Longitude in a polyline. I have written the following code , and when I make it a future,as follows:

```
  Future getPoints() async {
    List<dynamic> parsedJson = jsonDecode(
        'assets/busStops/stops_${widget.selectStation}.json');
    List<Marker> allMarkersByPosition = [];

    parsedJson.forEach((element) {
      List<dynamic> coords = element["bs"];

      coords.forEach((i) {
        double lat = double.tryParse(i["latitude"]);
        double lng = double.tryParse(i["longitude"]);

        return [
          LatLng(lat ?? 0.0, lng ?? 0.0),

        ];
      });
    });
  }
```

and reference getPoints(), here:

```
    child: FutureBuilder(
        future:
            _future,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
          List<dynamic> parsedJson = jsonDecode(snapshot.data);
          allMarkers = parsedJson.map((element) {
            return Marker(
                icon: customIcon,
                markerId: MarkerId(element["Latitude"].toString()),
                position: LatLng(element['Latitude'] ?? 0.0,
                    element['Longitude'] ?? 0.0));
          }).toList();

          return GoogleMap(
            initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                target: LatLng(-26.1711459, 27.9002758), zoom: 9.0),
            markers: Set.from(allMarkers),
            onMapCreated: mapCreated,
            polylines: Set<Polyline>.of(<Polyline>[
              Polyline(
                polylineId: PolylineId('line'),
                points: getPoints(),
                visible: true,
                color: Colors.blue
              )
            ]),
          );
        },
      ),
```

I get the error : The argument type 'Future' cant be assigned to the parameter type 'List'

Answer (score 0):

That is because your "getPoints" function is a `async` function, and thus, returns `Future`. This is normal, there is nothing wrong here.

You can solve this by wrapping your GoogleMap inside a FutureBuilder ( check here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ek8ZPdWj4Qo), and passing "getPoints" as a parameter to its function, something like that:

```
return FutureBuilder(
      future: getPoints(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }

        return GoogleMap(
          polylines: {
            Polyline(
                polylineId: PolylineId('line'),
                points: snapshot.data
                visible: true,
                color: Colors.blue
                ),
          },
        );
      },
    );
```

Comment: Thank you ! But I already have a Future builder for my markers, can i add another future?

Comment: Sure you can. You can have as many as you need, but take care to declare them on the initState, otherwise they will be recreated everytime you rebuild your map screen.

Comment: Thank you, I am experiencing another related issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59065836/flutter-google-maps-polyline-type-string-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-listlatl

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the first method. It never will actually return anything. This is because you use return inside a method you declare inside another method. When you use forEach, you are passing in a method to be applied to each element in that list. If you say return inside that method, you are simply returning from the method that you are passing to forEach.

Comment: Thank you, I am experiencing another related issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59065836/flutter-google-maps-polyline-type-string-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-listlatl